# List of lists: Changing all references with one assignment?

Tags: python

Rationale: I start a script with a list that contains multiple heaps. At every step, I want to "join" heaps, but keep both joined indexes pointing to the same element.

In short, given a list of mutable elements, such that `list[a] is list[b]` returns `True`, how can I assign (`list[a] = [new]`) while keeping `list[a]` and `list[b]` references to the same mutable container?

So for example, if each heap was represented by a letter, we would have

```
t is ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
t is ['ac', 'b', 'ac', 'd'] (0 and 2 merge)
t is ['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'd'] (0 and 1 merge, but since 0 also refers to 2, it is as if 0/2 and 1 merged... into 0/1/2)
```

at this stage, if I did a `set(map(id, t))`, I would expect it to only have TWO elements.

my problem is that I cannot seem to affect the object being pointed to directly, so I have to iterate over the entire list, picking out any ids that match either merge index, and assign directly.

is there any way to change the underlying object rather than all pointers to it?

Full Example of desired behavior:

```
>>> my_list = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
>>> merge(my_list, 0, 2) # mutates, returns None
>>> my_list
[['a', 'c'], ['b'], ['a', 'c']]
>>> my_list[0] is my_list[2]
True
>>> merge(my_list, 0, 1)
>>> my_list
[['a', 'c', 'b'], ['a', 'c', 'b'], ['a', 'c', 'b']]
>>> my_list[0] is my_list[1]
True
>>> my_list[1] is my_list[2]
True
```

The problem is that, if within `merge` I simply call

```
my_list[arg1] = my_list[arg2] = my_list[arg1]+my_list[arg2]
```

it ONLY affects the entries at `arg1` and `arg2`. I want it to affect any other entries that may point to the elements at either `my_list[arg1]` or `my_list[arg2]`, so that eventually `my_list` is just a collection of pointers to the same big heap, that has absorbed all the little ones.

Comment: I do not understand how this question is "too broad".

Comment: give a sample input/output to show us what you want...

Comment: given `A = ['a','a','c']` and  `B=['a','c','c']`, did you wanna `A==B is True` and  `A=B=['a','c']`?

Comment: no not quite. I added an example.

Comment: Python does not have pointers. Also note that `list` is a built-in type; you **should not** use it a s an identifier.

Comment: I know Python doesn't have pointers. However, it does have that newbie-confusing behavior where `[[]]*10` builds a list where an append to any element affects all the elements within it. This is what I want to harness.

Comment: Depends if the newbie does know some other language or not. In my experience, this confuses mostly ppl who already have C or C++ background, while those without (for instance) find this quite logical. You might be seing this wrong: it does _not_ affect "all the elements within it", but there is actually only _one_ element inside, but with multiple _references_! If you see it that way, it becomes very clear and logical that any change by one of the _references_ will be seen through all other _references_.

Comment: Just think of _objects_ having no names. Anything like names ("variables") or entries in container types is actually a _reference_ to an object, never an object itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is as close as you are going to get:

```
def merge(primary, first, second):
    primary[first] += primary[second]
    primary[second] = primary[first]

first = ['a']
second = ['b']
third = ['c']

main = [first, second, third]
print(main)
merge(main, 0, 2)
print(main)
assert main[0] is main[2]
merge(main, 0, 1)
print(main)
assert main[1] is main[2]
print(first, second, third)
```

and the printout:

```
[['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
[['a', 'c'], ['b'], ['a', 'c']]
[['a', 'c', 'b'], ['a', 'c', 'b'], ['a', 'c', 'b']]
(['a', 'c', 'b'], ['b'], ['c'])
```

As you can see, the list elements all end up being the same object, but the lists that went into the main list are not.

**edit**

Unfortunately, this also fails if you don't include the first list element in every merge.

So there are no short-cuts here.  If you want every element to either be the same element, or just be equal, you are going to have to traverse the list to get it done:

```
def merge(primary, first, second):
    targets = primary[first], primary[second]
    result = primary[first] + primary[second]
    for index, item in enumerate(primary):
        if item in targets:
            primary[index] = result
```

Comment: What happens when you reverse the order of the last merge, i.e. do `merge(main, 1, 0)`?

Comment: I think this also fails when you have 4 items to merge, and you merge into 2 lists of two elements each, and then merge those two lists together.  Try it with `main = [[x] for x in 'abcd'];merge(main, 0, 2);merge(main, 1, 3);merge(main, 0, 1);print(main)`

Comment: hmmm my first few passes seemed to validate it, but i'll unconfirm and do a few more

Comment: Yeah, I think I may have to drop down to something pointer-ed to handle this issue. I just can't afford that loop in there.

Answer (score 1):

Chain assignment:

```
>>> my_list = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]

>>> my_list[0] = my_list[2] = my_list[0]+my_list[2]

>>> my_list
[['a', 'c'], ['b'], ['a', 'c']]

>>> my_list[0] += [1,2,3]

>>> my_list
[['a', 'c', 1, 2, 3], ['b'], ['a', 'c', 1, 2, 3]]

>>>
```

If you do `a=c=a+c` first, it produce `a==c==_list_object_001`; when you do `a=b=a+b` 2nd, it produce `a==b==_list_object_002`, so it went wrong.
You can't do this even with a `pointer` if you don't take care of the order of assignment. I think you should maintain a map to get things right.

Comment: Maybe I'll use a numpy array of PyObj, and use clever slicing and `np.in1d`. I really appreciate how much effort you're putting, so I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: It's an interesting question. I thought it's simple until I drop into the trap :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, I don't think it's possible to do this using the mutability of python lists.  If you have elements X and Y, both of which are already amalgamations of other elements, and you want to merge them, list mutability will not be able to telegraph the change to both sides.  You can make X, Y and all the elements pointing at the same object as X be the same, or you can make X, Y and all the elements pointing at the same object as Y be the same, but not both.

I think the best bet is to define a custom object to represent the elements, which has a notion of parent nodes and ultimate parent nodes.

```
class Nodes(object):
    def __init__(self, input1):
        self.parent = None
        self.val = [input1]

    def ultimate_parent(self):
        if self.parent:
            return self.parent.ultimate_parent()
        else:
            return self

    def merge(self, child):
        self.ultimate_parent().val += child.ultimate_parent().val
        child.ultimate_parent().parent = self.ultimate_parent()

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.ultimate_parent().val)

def merge(node_list, i, j):
    node_list[i].merge(node_list[j])


list1 = [Nodes(x) for x in 'abcd']
print list1

merge(list1, 0, 2)
print list1
merge(list1, 1, 3)
print list1
merge(list1, 0, 1)
print list1
```

This will output:

```
[['a', 'c'],['b'],['a', 'c'],['d']]
[['a', 'c'],['b', 'd'],['a', 'c'],['b', 'd']]
[['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'],['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'],['a', 'c', 'b', 'd'],['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']]
```

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. Let me mull this over a bit.